# Tabbed Page Badge with FreshMVVM

Tags: xamarin, badge, tabbedpage, freshmvvm

I want to display a TabPage badge for indicating new messages using FreshMVVM.

I have found this Plugin.Badge NuGet package: https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge which works for Xamarin.Forms.

BUT I think the custom renderer uses the original TabbedPage class and it did not work with the FreshTabbedNavigationContainer from FreshMVVM because it is inherited.

Any idea how to show a TabbedPage badge in combination with FreshMVVM ?

Thanx

Marco

Comment: Did the below answer work for you?

Comment: Marco, did you find any solution?